# How can I improve my mathematical creativity?

Tags: soft-question

**NOTE: This post has been completely rewritten, but the ideas remain the same.**

I've been trying to figure out the divide between "good" and "great" mathematicians, and one metric I see repeatedly is "mathematical creativity". Great mathematicians seem to be able to pull new constructs out of thin air, whereas a merely "knowledgeable" mathematician can only mull about in the immediate facts.

This is where I feel I'm at personally in my mathematical career: mulling about in trivialities. I can derive maybe a few trivial implications from the assumptions, but often I need help in solving a problem, and once I see the solution's ingenuity I get the nagging feeling that I never would've been able to come up with those ideas myself.

I'm learning a lot of "things", but just learning the things hasn't seemed to improve my problem solving ability. Even solving math assignments, contest problems, working through proofs again and again, memorizing lemmas using spaced repetition software, all of it seems to have only made a marginal improvement. No matter how much math I seem to cram into my head, my problem solving creativity seems to remain at just about the same level.

Mathematical creativity is tricky, it's not like traditional creativity: it's paradoxically "creativity with constraint". How can one simultaneously think "outside the box", but "within the lattice" of mathematically reasonable ideas?

> What can be done to encourage **mathematical creativity**?

---

I think this warrants deeper discussion than we're giving it credit for.

There is likely no formula for creativity, otherwise it would be common knowledge by now. Some people will just be genetically more insightful than others. I think it would be unwise to end the discussion there, though.

Not everyone may be genetically built for bodybuilding, not everyone may be able to achieve the Schwarzenegger physique, but this doesn't invalidate the breadth of scientific research on bodybuilding. We've extensively developed bodybuilding techniques, we have rigorous means of discussing it.

I see the mind in the same way, with creativity as the muscle. Who's to say we there isn't a means of improving creativity like there's a means for building muscle, or a means for increasing our knowledge? Why shouldn't we expect that we simply lack the tools to discuss mathematical creativity?

Comment: @GeoffRobinson If creativity is in such high demand, then let's not immediately dismiss the discussion of creativity just because it lacks a "formula" and can only be encouraged. I don't believe a formula exists either, but there is still plenty which can be said about how to encourage creativity, johnnyb's answer is a great example of such insight. Of course, any insight will only be effective in combination with hard work.

Comment: You have to be born with the right kind of brain.So if you are >0 y.o., you have missed your chance.

Comment: I think the question is a good and important one.  I also think MathOverflow is not a good place for a discussion of it.  If you want the ensuing discussion this post deserves, a blog or wiki would be a better place for that.  Gerhard "Doesn't Have Good Answer Yet" Paseman, 2019.10.22.

Comment: @MattF. How's this? Sorry about the original.

Comment: This is no longer “unclear what you’re asking”, so I have voted to reopen.

Comment: I feel that this question is borderline for MO, and better suited to a blog, but I think we should give it a chance, so I am also voting to reopen.

Comment: (1/2) I think that your question was interesting, I hope that in the future some professor can to write notes or a book about *How can I improve my mathematical creativity?* in the context of the professional research in mathematics. I don't know how answer your question. On the other hand I know the videos from YouTube *Are mathematicians creative?* from the official channel **University of Bristol** and date March, 19th 2010, or *The creativity of mathematicians* from the official channel **Australian Academy of Science**, and date May, 21th 2018.

Comment: (2/2) I add these from the informative point of view, if you want to know these. Secondly I know other videos, in particular a TED Talks, in Spanish and books about creativity for general audiences. Also I think that one can to find other articles, literature about creativity from the scientific point of view and in popular science magazines including tips.

Answer (score 9):

It partially depends on what kind of "creative" you want to be.  Gian-Carlo Rota divided mathematicians into two groups, ["Problem-Solvers" and "Theorizers"](http://alessio.guglielmi.name/res/pst.html).  The problem-solvers solve new problems and the theorizers rethink old, already-solved problems until they are so obvious that they don't really need solutions.

There's some differences between the two groups, but I imagine that they are also similar in some important ways.

I think one thing that stymies creativity in mathematics is the emphasis on proofs.  I think that proofs are one of the things that makes mathematics great, but the hyper-focus on them actually distracts from teaching others to think great thoughts.  You almost never read about how someone first started thinking about something, or how they imagined it that allowed them to write the proof in the first place.  These things that take place in the imagination are rarely discussed, and, instead, mathematics focuses on the end-result, the proof, rather than the process that got there.

I think the key to creativity of both types (problem-solving and theorizing) is a willingness to think about a problem in a new way, or to take a new perspective on a field.  It's great to know all there is to know about a field, but sometimes this becomes a trap, such that you get used to thinking about a field in the same way as everyone else.  You get sucked down that hole, and don't even realize you are there.  For this reason, in [Meta Math](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B001M5JVM0), Chaitin suggests that newcomers are sometimes the best people to advance a field.  They aren't stuck in the same way of thinking as everyone else.

But, I think that there is another way out of the hole - being *widely* read.  And by this I don't just mean mathematics.  Read philosophy, physics, theology, engineering, poetry.  Many mathematical tools were developed by the physicists long before they were provable by the mathematicians, and they are much more likely to relay the reasoning that led to their ideas.  These things can give you a new perspective - an ability to see things that others don't see.

One other method I suggest for creativity is to [not worry about the impossible](https://mindmatters.ai/2019/08/doing-the-impossible-a-step-by-step-guide/).  There are, indeed impossible things.  However, most things that are "impossible" are only impossible due to certain assumptions (which are reasonable to everyone at the time, and sometimes so obvious that they are completely unstated).  One can be creative by imagining a world without some combination of those assumptions, and seeing what the new world looks like.  Even if removing the assumption is impossible, the practice of imagining the world like this is helpful.  It helps you practice in seeing through to what alternate sets of assumptions might look like, and helps your brain to recognize situations in which changing assumptions makes the world look more correct.

If you are a problem-solver, the practice of removing assumptions is extremely helpful.  If you are a theorizer, I would suggest looking into computer programming.  In computer programming, there is a concept called "refactoring", where you re-analyze existing code to see where there are redundancies and things can be reworked in a way that is simultaneously simpler and more powerful.  These tools and techniques can often be applied to mathematics to rework existing mathematics into a form that is likewise simultaneously simpler and more powerful.  See [here](https://journals.blythinstitute.org/ojs/index.php/cbi/article/view/29/30) for an example.

Comment: I concur.  I am preparing a presentation for an engineering group next month, and will soon add a link to it from my MathOverflow user page.  I appreciate your description about removing assumptions; I was able to employ this to help speed up a metagenome binning program. Of course you have to try a lot of unsuccessful combinations, but you have to try before you find a successful combination.  Removing assumptions sometimes reduces the combinatorial search.  Gerhard "Calls It 'Power Of Ignorance'" Paseman, 2019.10.22.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Very interesting! Being widely read is important in a number of facets. Perhaps we won't be proving theorems using facts we've learned from microbiology, but having a breadth of knowledge is certainly a good exercise for neuroplasticity. It seems we're circling a theme of "creativity arising from freedom". When the mind is constrained to a mode of thinking, creativity dwindles. This I suppose is also the benefit of removing assumptions, as you suggest. I'll certainly practice this soon.

Comment: I'm going to tentatively leave your answer unaccepted due to the open-ended nature of the question. It might gain some traction as a "big-list". If not, I'll certainly accept yours :)